# document.form.submit() with confirm()

Tags: javascript, forms, confirm

I have successfully used JavaScript `confirm()` using the `onClick` event handler.

```
<input type="submit" onClick="return confirm(....);" />
```

And I have also successfully used `confirm` using the `onSubmit`

```
<form onSubmit="return confirm(....);">
```

Now my issue is, there is one specific situation where I want to submit the form by not clicking and just using `document.myform.submit()` but when ever I do it, it seems to bypass the confirm in the onSubmit event.

How do I use `document.whateverform.submit()` together with confirm()?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a duplicate, have you searched for the answer already?

Comment: `if(confirm(......)){document.whateverform.submit();}`

Comment: I definitely searched and I can find answers on how to use confirm, or how to submit a form using submit(), and many thing similar but once I put them together, that is the only time it does not work and I cannot find that answer on StackOverflow... or maybe I am not searching hard enough.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `el.addEventListener` instead of inline?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I always had the impression that the confirm has to be triggered by a submit and if the confirm is true then the submit will continue. 

While looking at this:

if(confirm(......)){document.whateverform.submit();}

Looks like the confirm will already run and only if it is true then submit the form, but what triggers the confirm? And it should happen by clicking. Actually PHP is writing the JS code, do I have to add the confirm to an onLoad?

Comment: @Miszy sorry, addEventListener is beyond my knowledge. I really do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are fired when a user performs an action that triggers a state change.  Browsers cannot let an onsubmit handler run when the .submit function is called directly via JavaScript.  Think about what would happen to code like this:

```
<form onsubmit="if(someCondition) { this.submit(); }">
...
</form>
```

If the event fired from the javascript-driven submit, that would trigger an infinite loop because onsubmit calls submit, which calls onsubmit, and so on.  I know some people may question whether that is a good pattern, but I have seen it.

You should probably avoid direct calls to form.submit altogether and replace them with a call to the same function, like so:

```
function confirmFormSubmission() {
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');
}

function submitForm(f) {
  if (confirmFormSubmission()) {
    f.submit();
  }
}

...

<form onsubmit="return confirmFormSubmission()">
....
</form>
```

Any place in your JavaScript code that calls form.submit, replace it with a call to submitForm instead to make sure it works consistently.